# Unit Tests for Asynch Callout from a LWC

Tags: apex, unit-test, lightning-web-components, asynchronous-testing

I have implemented several callouts using the Continuation object based on the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_continuations.htm). But there is no reference for unit tests. The section in the developer guide only shows how to test with instance methods not with Aura Enabled static methods. I have tried to follow along and found one other discussion on Stack Exchange. But I don't seem to get the correct data into my continuation method. It throws a null pointer exception when I try to get the response status code.

Below is my Continuation and my call back method

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true Continuation=true)
    public static Object resetPassWord(String federationId) {
        URLEndpoints__mdt endpoints = [
                SELECT Url__c,
                        HTTP_Method__c
                FROM URLEndpoints__mdt
                WHERE DeveloperName = :'Okta_Reset'
                LIMIT 1
        ];
        Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
        con.continuationMethod = 'processResetResponse';

        con.state = 'hello world';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod(endpoints.HTTP_Method__c);
        req.setEndpoint(endpoints.Url__c + federationId +
                '/lifecycle/reset_password?sendEmail=false');       
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'SSWS' + Label.OktaApiToken);
        con.addHttpRequest(req);
        return con;
    }
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Object processResetResponse(List<String> labels, Object state) {
        HttpResponse res = Continuation.getResponse(labels[0]);       
        if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            return res.getBody();
        }
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return res.getBody();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my unit test -  I was just trying to pass anything into the call back to see if I get get a value. That is why the list of strings and I also tried setting the response.statuscode. But no luck.

```
 @IsTest
    static void testOktaPasswordReset(){
        List<String>strings = new List<String>{'200'};
        String state = 'State';
        Test.startTest();
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setBody('Mock response body');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        Continuation continuation =(Continuation)PatientOktaController.resetPassWord('123456');
        Test.setContinuationResponse('Continuation-1', response);
        //Map<String, HttpRequest> requestMap = obj.getRequests();
        Test.setContinuationResponse('Continuation -1', response);
        Object result = Test.invokeContinuationMethod(PatientOktaController.processResetResponse(strings, state), continuation);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard back from Salesforce about this today. The long and the short is that you can not test Static Continuation Methods. There is a workaround though.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/05/apex-continuations-implementation-and-testing-in-aura-lwc.html.

I will post my code later if I get this working.

Comment: why do you even need continuation now? isn't that deprecated now.

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_apex_request_limit.htm